# PHP manipulando SESSION - Como desligar VÁRIAS SESSÕES

Tags: php, session, login

Bom dia!

É importante notar que essa pergunta é sobre VÁRIAS SESSÕES, já que pesquisei no forum e as perguntas sobre assunto parecidos remete somente a uma sessão.

Após vários testes para aprender $_SESSION eu abri diversas sessões no meu servidor e navegador. Agora quando tento abrir novas sou bloqueado, ou as variáveis não passam para a página seguinte. Trata-se se um simples sistema de login com MySQLi e $_SESSION.

Código exemplo: **Página 1**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['validade']=date('H:m:s');
$_SESSION['nome']=$_POST['nomePrimeiro'];
$_SESSION['segundoNome']=$_POST['nomeSegundo'];
*** (resto do código)
?>
```

Código exemplo: **Página 2**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['nome'];
$_SESSION['segundoNome'];

if($_SESSION['validade']>$_SESSION['validade']+'1:00:00'){
(...logout)
}ELSE{
(...autoriza abertura da página inicial)
}
?>
```